# Query a collection for the latest unique object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**Question:** Lets say I have the following objects in a collection:

How would I return one record per `"product_id"` and only the one with the highest `"version"` number? And is this possible to do within mongoose?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f765564b10883c1800002a"),
    "total_invoice_fob_case" : 86.70999999999999,
    "status" : "Draft",
    "discount" : "3.40",
    "effective_date" : ISODate("2013-08-01T06:00:00.000Z"),
    "version" : 2,
    "controlstate" : "AB",
    "controlstate_id" : ObjectId("54d510e9e3d793f581b6bb27"),
    "product" : "Product A",
    "product_id" : ObjectId("54f75b5e4b1088801a000627"),
    "size" : "1.75LTR",
    "size_id" : ObjectId("5418a3dd750b4294c2cb3a47"),
    "vendor" : "BEAM SUNTORY",
    "vendor_id" : ObjectId("54ef5aa74b1088781b000169"),
    "product_state_code" : "123",
    "net_fob_cost" : 86.70999999999999,
    "change_reason" : [ 
        "Other"
    ],
    "submitted" : {
        "submitted_date" : ISODate("2014-05-16T06:00:00.000Z")
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f765564b10883c1800002b"),
    "total_invoice_fob_case" : 86.70999999999999,
    "status" : "Draft",
    "discount" : "4.40",
    "effective_date" : ISODate("2013-08-01T06:00:00.000Z"),
    "version" : 3,
    "controlstate" : "AB",
    "controlstate_id" : ObjectId("54d510e9e3d793f581b6bb27"),
    "product" : "Product A",
    "product_id" : ObjectId("54f75b5e4b1088801a000627"),
    "size" : "1.75LTR",
    "size_id" : ObjectId("5418a3dd750b4294c2cb3a47"),
    "vendor" : "BEAM SUNTORY",
    "vendor_id" : ObjectId("54ef5aa74b1088781b000169"),
    "product_state_code" : "123",
    "net_fob_cost" : 86.70999999999999,
    "change_reason" : [ 
        "Other"
    ],
    "submitted" : {
        "submitted_date" : ISODate("2014-05-16T06:00:00.000Z")
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f765564b10883c1800002c"),
    "total_invoice_fob_case" : 86.70999999999999,
    "status" : "Draft",
    "discount" : "3.40",
    "effective_date" : ISODate("2013-08-01T06:00:00.000Z"),
    "version" : 2,
    "controlstate" : "AB",
    "controlstate_id" : ObjectId("54d510e9e3d793f581b6bb27"),
    "product" : "Product B",
    "product_id" : ObjectId("54f75b5e4b1088801a000628"),
    "size" : "1.75LTR",
    "size_id" : ObjectId("5418a3dd750b4294c2cb3a47"),
    "vendor" : "BEAM SUNTORY",
    "vendor_id" : ObjectId("54ef5aa74b1088781b000169"),
    "product_state_code" : "123",
    "net_fob_cost" : 86.70999999999999,
    "change_reason" : [ 
        "Other"
    ],
    "submitted" : {
        "submitted_date" : ISODate("2014-05-16T06:00:00.000Z")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an **[aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)** that first sorts the documents in the collection by version number descending using a [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort) pipeline stage, then groups the ordered documents by `product_id` using the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) operator. Within the grouping use the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator on **`$$ROOT`** to return the first document in the sorted group:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$sort": { "version": -1 }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$product_id",
            "value": {
                "$first": "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "product_id": "$_id",
            "status": "$value.status",
            "version": "$value.version",
            "product" : "$value.product"
        }    
    }
 ];

// Mongoose aggregation
Model.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, res) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log(res); // 
});
```

**Console Output**:

```
[ 
    {
        "product_id" : ObjectId("54f75b5e4b1088801a000628"),
        "status" : "Draft",
        "version" : 2,
        "product" : "Product B"
    }, 
    {
        "product_id" : ObjectId("54f75b5e4b1088801a000627"),
        "status" : "Draft",
        "version" : 3,
        "product" : "Product A"
    }
]
```

-- **UPDATE** --

To project the full document, replace the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) pipeline with the following:

```
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "product": "$value"
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "product" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("54f765564b10883c1800002c"),
                "total_invoice_fob_case" : 86.7099999999999940,
                "status" : "Draft",
                "discount" : "3.40",
                "effective_date" : ISODate("2013-08-01T06:00:00.000Z"),
                "version" : 2,
                "controlstate" : "AB",
                "controlstate_id" : ObjectId("54d510e9e3d793f581b6bb27"),
                "product" : "Product B",
                "product_id" : ObjectId("54f75b5e4b1088801a000628"),
                "size" : "1.75LTR",
                "size_id" : ObjectId("5418a3dd750b4294c2cb3a47"),
                "vendor" : "BEAM SUNTORY",
                "vendor_id" : ObjectId("54ef5aa74b1088781b000169"),
                "product_state_code" : "123",
                "net_fob_cost" : 86.7099999999999940,
                "change_reason" : [ 
                    "Other"
                ],
                "submitted" : {
                    "submitted_date" : ISODate("2014-05-16T06:00:00.000Z")
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "product" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("54f765564b10883c1800002b"),
                "total_invoice_fob_case" : 86.7099999999999940,
                "status" : "Draft",
                "discount" : "4.40",
                "effective_date" : ISODate("2013-08-01T06:00:00.000Z"),
                "version" : 3,
                "controlstate" : "AB",
                "controlstate_id" : ObjectId("54d510e9e3d793f581b6bb27"),
                "product" : "Product A",
                "product_id" : ObjectId("54f75b5e4b1088801a000627"),
                "size" : "1.75LTR",
                "size_id" : ObjectId("5418a3dd750b4294c2cb3a47"),
                "vendor" : "BEAM SUNTORY",
                "vendor_id" : ObjectId("54ef5aa74b1088781b000169"),
                "product_state_code" : "123",
                "net_fob_cost" : 86.7099999999999940,
                "change_reason" : [ 
                    "Other"
                ],
                "submitted" : {
                    "submitted_date" : ISODate("2014-05-16T06:00:00.000Z")
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to project the full object without specifying every key/value?

Comment: @Fostah Yes, you can project a new field that holds the whole document from the previous group operation otherwise you will have to specify new fields with the specific properties. I've updated my answer to this effect.

Comment: @chridam, you don't need the projection anymore if you are storing the entire document in product to begin with the grouping.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for Mongo's [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/). You can extrapolate from [this example](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/#return-largest-and-smallest-cities-by-state) how to approach the problem.

Update: To retrieve one per `product_id` with the highest version you would need to also use [`$first`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#_S_first):

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {$sort: {product_id: 1, version: -1}}, // sort first so that $first pulls the correct record
  {$group: {
    _id: {product_id: '$product_id'}, // group by the product_id
    product: {$first: $$ROOT} // only return the first document per group
  }}
]);
```